# Identity Symbol in Craig's Interpolation Theorem

Tags: logic

"
In each of the following, $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are sentences such that
the identity symbol occurs in at most one of them, and $\varphi \vDash \psi$; however,
$\varphi$, $\psi$ have no Craig interpolant in which the identity symbol does not occur:

(i) $\varphi$ is $(\exists x)(P(x) \land \neg P(x))$, $\psi$ is $(\exists x)Q(x)$;

(ii) $\varphi$ is $(\exists x)Q(x)$, $\psi$ is $(\exists x)(P(x) \lor \neg P(x))$;

(iii) $\varphi$ is $(\forall xy)(x \equiv y)$, $\psi$ is $(\forall xy)(P(x) \leftrightarrow P(y))$. "

Comment: "φ and ψ are sentences such that the identity symbol occurs in **at most** one of them"

Comment: "at most one" means not in both, but can be neither in the first nor in the second.

Comment: The issue is that the two formulas have no common predicates; thus, we cannot build a "usual" interpolant that must have **only** the **common** predicates: there are none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be useful to state the Theorem in slightly different form [see Raymond Smullyan, [First Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&pg=PA127), page 127]: if $\varphi, \psi$ have at least one predicate in common, then there is an interpolant sentence. If they have no predicate in common, then either $\psi$ is valid or $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable.

The two cases can be reduced to one, using $\top$ and $\bot$. If $\varphi, \psi$ have no predicate in common, we have that:

> if $\psi$ is valid, the interpolant is $\top$, while if $\varphi$ is unsatisfiable, then the interpolant is $\bot$.

Thus, we can adapt this "trick" to the above examples using $\exists x(x \ne x)$ for (i):

> $(∃x)(P(x) ∧ ¬P(x)) \vDash \exists x(x \ne x)$ and $\exists x(x \ne x) \vDash (∃x)Q(x)$,

because $(∃x)(P(x)∧¬P(x))$ is a contradicition (it is unsatisfiable).

The same for (ii), where $(∃x)(P(x)∨¬P(x))$ is valid, using $\forall x (x=x)$.